# Getting input in Java using nextInt

Tags: java, input

I am coding a Java Program in which user inputs marks of three subject and gets their grades based on that but getting an error in getting input. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b, c;
        double avg;
        String gr;
        System.out.println("marks in Physics,Chemistry,Biology");
        a = in .nextInt();
        b = in .nextInt();
        c = in .nextInt();
        avg = (a + b + c) / 3;
        if (avg > 80) {
            gr = "distinction";
        }
        if (avg >= 60 && avg < 80) {
            gr = "first division";
        }
        if (avg >= 45 && avg < 60) {
            gr = "second division";
        }
        if (avg >= 40 && avg < 45) {
            gr = "pass";
        } else {
            gr = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println(gr);
    }
}
```

It shows this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Prog.main(Prog.java:9)
```

What am I doing wrong, How can I solve it?

Comment: What have you typed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, my guess is that the input you're typing is not an integer - either text or maybe a number with a decimal point?

If it's that you need to be able to handle numbers with decimal points, I'd suggest making the variables `a`, `b` and `c` either `double` or `float` types, and then using `in.nextDouble()` or `in.nextFloat()`.

If you need to handle non-numeric input, for example, if someone enters "one" instead of "1", then you'll need to read the input values as Strings, with `in.next()`, and then convert them to integers (or floats or doubles if you need decimal numbers), and catch the exception if it doesn't convert. As an example of how you might do something like this:

```
String inValue = in.next();
try {
    a = Integer.parseInt(inValue);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // Do something else, like exiting with an error message or setting the value to 0.
}
```

Lastly, check your conditions for the scores, I think at least one of them is incorrect (hint: try your code with scores right on the grade boundaries - e.g. 40, 45, 60 and 80).

Answer (score 4):

From the docs of the [nextInt method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> Throws: InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the
>   Integer regular expression, or is out of range

So you should handle this exception if the user enters wrong input. Could be like this:

```
    boolean inputOk = false;
    do{
        System.out.println("enter your first grade");
        try {
            a = in .nextInt();
            inputOk = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException  e) {
            System.out.println("not a valid number");
            in.nextLine(); // to reset the scanner
        }
    }while (!inputOk);
```

Do the same with the other variables. You could even write another method to do this and avoid repeating yourself (DRY principle)

Answer (score -2):

The input code works for me, but your if statements are flawed.  You need more 'else' statements:

```
if (avg > 80) {
  gr = "distinction";
} else if (avg >= 60 && avg < 80) {
  gr = "first division";
} else if (avg >= 45 && avg < 60) {
  gr = "second division";
} else if (avg >= 40 && avg < 45) {
  gr = "pass";
} else {
  gr = "fail";
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect; the code you have posted and the original code is equivalent.

Comment: **"You need more 'else' statements?"** - Huh?

Comment: How can you possibly claim that my code and the original are equivalent? Have you tried running them? Let's say avg is equal to 83. The original code will set gr to distinction but then the last if-else will set it to fail. My code does not.

Comment: Apologies, you're absolutely right - I was just confused by your assertion that "you need more 'else' statements". Maybe an edit to cover what you say in the comment above, just to make it a bit clearer - Arnav's comment suggests I wasn't the only one who missed your point.